# Wrong numbers of likes trought graph.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I watch this page:

http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334

the likes are 42.

if I try to retrieve the number of the likes through facebook api:

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334

```
{
   "name": "Advice for your next failure - Busy Family",
   "is_published": true,
   "description": "Ascolta l'album su Rockit.",
   "about": "Ascolta l'album su Rockit.",
   "app_id": 162683947163843,
   "category": "Album",
   "id": "491498180869281",
   "link": "http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334",
   "likes": 2
}
```

I've got 2 likes, why?

The open graph data is this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Advice for your next failure - Busy Family"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="album"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Rockit.it"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1747861721"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="763518965"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="162683947163843"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Ascolta l'album su Rockit. “Advice for your next failure”  è l’opera prima dei Busy Family, fresca band folk-rock di stanza tra Trieste e Belluno, nata dall’idea di..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rockit.it/thumbx200x200/copertine/20334.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number on the Like button isn't just the like count; this is mentioned on the LIke button documentation, for more detailed stats you can use the url_like FQL table:

`select normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,
commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count from link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334'`

Results now are

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "normalized_url": "http://www.rockit.it/BusyFamily/album/advice-for-your-next-failure/20334", 
      "share_count": 16, 
      "like_count": 23, 
      "comment_count": 3, 
      "total_count": 42, 
      "commentsbox_count": 0, 
      "comments_fbid": 377087125706867, 
      "click_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

`total_count` is the number shown on the Like button

Comment: So basically there is an assumption here that if a user "shares" the URL, it should count towards the `"XXX others like this."`?

Comment: Yep, this is mentioned under **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?** on the [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: Right there at the bottom hey? :P I had no idea this number was tied to other actions. Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and OP: the result returned in the Graph API isn't the same at the moment, i think there's something on the roadmap or a migration setting for the app which resolves this